# How to bypass build-in variables?

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-studio-2

I've been busy working with Gamemaker Studio 2 and I've noticed that it has quite some build-in variables. Like 'x', 'y', 'speed', 'health'. 
These variables have already a set function, and it overlaps the variable I've set by myself.

I was earlier looking at a tutorial that adds an underscore to all his variables so these will appear on top once written out completely, While it worked, I didn't liked the look of all these uinderscores. hence why I was asking myself if it could be done easier.

So, does anyone knows an other method to make custom variables without the chance to have the build-in variables overlapping them?

Comment: GMS2 highlights built-in variables and functions with other color. And if you want to use GMS you should know built-in variables (most part of them).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some time playing around, I've found my own way.

I can just use my own variables without the underscore at the end, and if it happens that I need to use a variable with the same name as a build-in variable. Then I'll simply add 'my' at the front, like `mySpeed` or `myhealth`.

These can appear even earlier in the intellisense as well as 'my' is pretty unique conpared to the build-in variables.

Comment: To the one who downvoted both my own question and answer out of sudden after 2,5 years, please give me a reason to do so.